# Master-detail app: name of cell is my string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, master-detail

By started with a master detail application template with Xcode 6 beta 2, when user clicked the "+" button to add a cell, the cell take by default the date for name. I've add an alert view (that contain a text field) when the user clicked the "+" button. He had to tape a name into the text field and the value is store in a string that I've declared. And my question is how I can define the name of the cell with the string (I wan't the cell's name is my string).

That's certainly in this code:

```
 NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

or

```
[newManagedObject setValue:stringNewItem forKey:@"nomRecette"];
```

Thank's for your answers.

Gilles

Answer (score 0):

Add the value to your dataSource of the tableView (you probably have a NSArray for that), and force it to reload after you dismiss the alert view!